# Is it possible to use react hooks in a component that will be rendered with renderToString

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom, react-dom-server, render-to-string

I have a component that contains react-router-dom's `Link` but throws the error below when I pass the component in the react-dom `renderToString`

```
Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

Can't I pass a component that has react hooks into `renderToString` functions?

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

  const html = renderToString(<Contact />);
  console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the `useHref()` hook inside `<Contact/>` component. But
`useHref()` hook must be used in a Router context, the error throws at line [lib/hooks.tsx#L36](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.3.0/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L36). Let's see the source code of `useHref()` hook:

```
export function useHref(to: To): string {
  invariant(
    useInRouterContext(),
    // TODO: This error is probably because they somehow have 2 versions of the
    // router loaded. We can help them understand how to avoid that.
    `useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`
  );

  let { basename, navigator } = React.useContext(NavigationContext);
  let { hash, pathname, search } = useResolvedPath(to);

  let joinedPathname = pathname;
  if (basename !== "/") {
    let toPathname = getToPathname(to);
    let endsWithSlash = toPathname != null && toPathname.endsWith("/");
    joinedPathname =
      pathname === "/"
        ? basename + (endsWithSlash ? "/" : "")
        : joinPaths([basename, pathname]);
  }

  return navigator.createHref({ pathname: joinedPathname, search, hash });
}
```

We can use [`<StaticRouter>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/ssr#without-a-data-router) to do the SSR, `StaticRouter` component uses [Router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.3.0/packages/react-router-dom/server.tsx#L74) component underly, `Router` uses [NavigationContext.Provider](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.3.0/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L232) and [LocationContext.Provider](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.3.0/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L233) components to provide the context value to its children components, then you can use `useHref()` hook in these children components.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { describe, it } from "@jest/globals";
import { Routes, Route, useHref } from 'react-router-dom';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom/server';

const Contact = ({ to }) => {
  const href = useHref(to)
  return <pre>{href}</pre>
}

describe('76209110', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const html = renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={'/courses'}>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="courses"
            element={<Contact to="advanced-react" />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </StaticRouter>
    )
    console.log('html: ', html)
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.log
    html:  <pre>/courses/advanced-react</pre>

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/76209110/index.test.tsx:24:13)

 PASS  stackoverflow/76209110/index.test.tsx
  76209110
    ✓ should pass (66 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.42 s
```

package version:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
```